# How to operate the undo-redo tree in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, undo-tree-mode

I just hit `SPC a u` and it opened the undo-redo tree. Now I can't operate it.
I go on the tree, press enter and nothing happen. I can't close it!
 Either `:q` is unrecognized. How do I operate this ?

Comment: Although this is not technically cross-posting, emacs.stackexchange.com forum participants should be aware that there is an identical thread in reddit.com:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/54hptg/how_does_the_undo_tree_work_in_spacemacs/?st=itje04nl&sh=d638bc81

Comment: what is `SPC a u`?

Answer (score 12):

On `Vim` editing style, naturally:

- <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> to navigate through the tree up and down.
- <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> to switch branches.

When using `Emacs` editing style:

- <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd> to navigate through the tree up and down.
- <kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd> to switch branches.

On `both` editing styles:

- <kbd>q</kbd> or <kbd>C-g</kbd> to quit and leave in current state.
- <kbd>C-q</kbd> to abort changes.

**Note**: *Undo-Tree* is a very powerful package and has lots of useful/cool features that are comprehensively explained only in its source code embedded documentation, which could be visualized by calling:

```
M-x finder-commentary <RET>
```

then type:

```
undo-tree <RET>
```

Or take a look at the Online [**Undo-tree documentation**](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/undo-tree.html)

---

Other useful commands:

- <kbd>d</kbd> Toggle diff display.
- <kbd>t</kbd> Toggle display of time-stamps.
- <kbd>s</kbd> Toggle keyboard selection mode.
- <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd><</kbd> Scroll left
- <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> Scroll right

Answer (score 2):

- `h` and `l` to move from branch to branch (the current one is highlighted).
- `C-n` and `C-p` to move up and down the tree.

When you are ready press `q` and you are out.